# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo during runtime in logcat

Tags: android

The app crashes saying "Unfortunately app has stopped" when i run in the emulator. and shows the error AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in my logcat. Please help me to fix this error since i am new to java and android. 
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.kiran.lamolamo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText Input;
    TextView Text;

    MyDBHandler dbHandler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.buckysInput);
        Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buckysText);
dbHandler= new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        Products product = new Products(Input.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addproduct(product);
        printDatabase();


    }
public void deleteButtonClicked(View view) {
    String inputText = Input.getText().toString();
    dbHandler.deleteproduct(inputText);
    printDatabase();
}
    public void printDatabase() {

        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        Text.setText(dbString);
        Input.setText("");

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kiran.lamolamo.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/buckysInput" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/addUser"
        android:onClick="addButtonClicked"
        android:text="Add User"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buckysInput"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="deleteButtonClicked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addUser"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buckysInput"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buckysInput"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:id="@+id/buckysText"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Products.java

```
package com.example.kiran.lamolamo;
public class Products {
private int _id;
    private String _productname;
public Products(){};
    public Products(String productname) {
        this.set_productname(productname);
    }
    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String get_productname() {
        return _productname;
    }

    public void set_productname(String _productname) {
        this._productname = _productname;
    }
}
```

MyDBHandler.java

package com.example.kiran.lamolamo;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VESION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "products";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";




    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VESION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String Query = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "TEXT" +
        ");";
        db.execSQL(Query);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

 public void addproduct(Products product) {
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME,product.get_productname());
     SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
     db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
     db.close();
 }

    public void deleteproduct(String productName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM" + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE"+COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";");

    }

public String databaseToString() {
String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE 1";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Query,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"))!=null) {
    dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
        dbString+="\n";
    }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
}
```

logcat

```
11-11 18:53:20.979 30992-30992/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-11 18:53:21.063 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener
11-11 18:53:21.067 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 242: Landroid/app/Application;.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
11-11 18:53:21.067 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-11 18:53:21.143 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener
11-11 18:53:21.143 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 245: Landroid/app/Application;.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
11-11 18:53:21.143 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-11 18:53:21.143 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.kiran.lamolamo, real application class is null.
11-11 18:53:21.175 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
11-11 18:53:21.179 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
11-11 18:53:21.183 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1704 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
11-11 18:53:21.183 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x025e
11-11 18:53:21.183 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
11-11 18:53:21.183 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1704 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
11-11 18:53:21.183 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0060
11-11 18:53:21.295 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEproducts": syntax error
11-11 18:53:21.295 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-11 18:53:21.303 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62c4288)
11-11 18:53:21.303 30992-30992/com.example.kiran.lamolamo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kiran.lamolamo/com.example.kiran.lamolamo.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEproducts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEproducts(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTproductnameTEXT);
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEproducts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEproducts(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTproductnameTEXT);
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
                                                                                at com.example.kiran.lamolamo.MyDBHandler.onCreate(MyDBHandler.java:31)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
                                                                                at com.example.kiran.lamolamo.MyDBHandler.databaseToString(MyDBHandler.java:55)
                                                                                at com.example.kiran.lamolamo.MainActivity.printDatabase(MainActivity.java:42)
                                                                                at com.example.kiran.lamolamo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real issue

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEproducts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEproducts(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTproductnameTEXT);

The cause

```
String Query = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
        COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "TEXT" +
    ");";
```

The solution

```
String Query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                            ^ add a space

        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                     ^ add a space                     ^^ add a comma, and space 

        COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT" +
                              ^ add a space
    ");";
```

I like to *debug log* my queries before they are executed.

```
if ( debugQuery ) {

    Log.d("MyDBHelper", "Executing query [ " + query + " ]");
}

db.execSQL(Query);
```

Seems as if you will also have the same issue when `onUpgrade` is called.

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
```

Again, missing a space

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
                                ^ here
```

And again on your query...

```
String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE 1";
```

Should be

```
String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";
                                                ^ here
```

Comment: Thank you Matt Clark for your answer. I have edited my code according to you and it really helped me to run the code.  The app runs but stops when I click either of the bottom. Is there any wrong in my code?. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The crash cause is a mistype, in your `MyDBHandler.java` you forgot 5 spaces and 1 comma.

It must be

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
...
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String Query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT" +
    ");";
    db.execSQL(Query);
}
...
```